# Disabling user input within a Marionette collection view - that is being updated by other parts of the application

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone-relational

Need to disable input buttons for items within a Marionette collection view.

Normally I'd just do:

```
TheView.$el.find('input').prop('disabled', true);
```

That should disabled all input elements within the view.

The problem I am having is that other parts of the application are updating that view, as a result anything new that comes into the view is not disabled.

What is a good pattern for dealing with this situation?

Comment: What kind of view are you using? And how is it updated? Your approach is fine I think, just apply it again after changes occur.

Comment: your problem description is not clear, how does other part updating the view? and where do you place the code above in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INHO its not very good to work with ItemView elements from collection view - its better to use custom event or move disable logick to item view.

In case you have other modules updating the view - if i were you i would move disable term in ItemView template - in this case any update will check this term and render input correctlly.